# Downloading a file from an Amazon shared link

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been tasked with finding a way to save files given a link to someones amazon bucket. These files are attachments uploaded to a ticketing system, and when i used their API to pull the ticket out, i am given a link like the one below(I removed all the private stuff and replaced with XXXXX)

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.XXXXXXX.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/36012348362/original/1.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180808T205357Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host

As you can see, the links time out after 1 day. I am connecting 2 API's together, and i need to be able to upload an actual file into the second API instead of just placing a link that times out after a day. I have tried to use Webclient downloadfileAsync, but all i get is a blank file output. I can go to the link in my browser and do a right click, save image as, so i know its possible, but i havent had any luck programatically. Below is the code snipped i am currently using to try and download it.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{                    
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(url), "image.jpg");
}
```

Any insight or help would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a similar issue once, programmatically downloading something - it worked in the browser but not from my code.  I found that I had to spoof the user agent of my request, so that the server saw me as a browser.

Comment: That sounds promising, how did you spoof the server to think you were a browser?

Comment: Any chance the file was empty because you queried it before the async download completed?

Comment: I thought about that possibility as well, i was just watching the size of the file in file explorer. I gave it a good minute or so though. I am going to test with a non-async run and see what happens... Ok i tried it. IT WORKED!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by not using the async version of DownloadFile. Thanks to all the people who helped me resolve this.